# Remove elements in one numpy array from another numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I would like to subtract element from a numpy array that don't exist in another.

Example:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([1,2])
```

Result:

```
[3, 4]
```

Comment: I rephrased it a bit and reopened the question.

Comment: What do you want returned if a value that doesn't occur in b occurs more than once in a, like if `a = np.array([1,2,3,3])`?

Comment: Are both of your arrays 1-dimensional ones? Depending on that you might want to adapt different strategies. The suggested `setdiff1d` will work only for 1D arrays.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Numpy's [`setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) function:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([1, 2])

c = np.setdiff1d(a, b)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[3 4]
```

If duplicate values are not to be removed, then you can use Numpy's [`in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) function:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([1, 2])

c = a[~np.in1d(a, b)]

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[3 4 3 4]
```

Comment: But this only keeps _unique_ elements, e.g. if 3 occurred twice in the original it will be only once in the result.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I'm assuming that's what the OP wants, since the question doesn't mention this.

Comment: That's why I'm assuming he doesn't want it :-)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I've added a workaround that keeps duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep duplicates, you can index using `in1d`:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,3])
>>> b = np.array([1,2])
>>> np.in1d(a, b)  # Boolean array that says where a is in b
array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> ~np.in1d(a, b))  # Boolean array that says where a is NOT in b
array([False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> a[~np.in1d(a, b)]  # Use the Boolean array as index to get your answer
array([3, 3])
```